# How to force Mac to recognise USB drive

Tags: macos, usb

During my app development cycle, I'm frequently re-connecting my Garmin watch as a USB drive to my Mac, and am frustrated having to wait for the sometimes 30+ seconds before the Mac automatically recognises the new connection.

Is there any way to force the Mac to re-establish the connection?
Catalina 10.15.6

Answer (score 0):

It seems the delay is not in the Mac after all. Windows has the same issue.

The delay is in the Garmin watch. As it detects the connection with the Mac, it goes through some contortions before it starts to behave like an external USB drive.

Speculations are that it takes this amount of time to saves its state, but it's all proprietary, so who knows?